# How to list Amazon AMIs , providing the region and the OS type using boto3.

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

The describe_images option of the client gives one or more of the images (AMIs, AKIs, and ARIs) available to you. Images available to you include public images, private images that you own, and private images owned by other AWS accounts but for which you have explicit launch permissions.

How can I get the specific AMI id for a particular OS and Region , I need.

for eg: Amazon Linux AMI in North Virginia region in my account is ami-9be6f38c, how to get this information through boto3.

Thank You.

Comment: I decide to delete my answer. Good luck and have fun with the boto3 describe_image filters. ;-)  Let me know if I should restore the updated answer with filter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Could you clarify?

Comment: If there is no further comments, I am going to delete my updated answer.